# How to get Google Dataflow to write to a BigQuery table name from the input data?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm new to Dataflow/Beam. I'm trying to write some data to BigQuery. I want the destination table name to be brought in from the previous stage a map entry keyed "table". But I couldn't find out how I pass this table name through the pipeline to BigQuery. Here's where I'm stuck.. any ideas what do to next?

```
pipeline
// ...
//////// I guess I shouldn't output TableRow here?
.apply("ToBQRow", ParDo.of(new DoFn<Map<String, String>, TableRow>() {
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
        ////////// WHAT DO I DO WITH "table"?
        String table = c.element().get("table");
        TableRow row = new TableRow();
        // ... set some records
        c.output(row);
    }
}))
.apply(BigQueryIO.writeTableRows().to(/* ///// WHAT DO I WRITE HERE?? */)
    .withSchema(schema)
    .withWriteDisposition(
        BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
));
```

Comment: You should look into [DynamicDestinations](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.13.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/DynamicDestinations.html) for this

Answer (score 3):

You can use [DynamicDestinations](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.13.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/DynamicDestinations.html) for that.

As an example I create some dummy data and I'll use the last word as the key:

```java
p.apply("Create Data", Create.of("this should go to table one",
                                 "I would like to go to table one",
                                 "please, table one",
                                 "I prefer table two",
                                 "Back to one",
                                 "My fave is one",
                                 "Rooting for two"))
.apply("Create Keys", ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, KV<String,String>>() {
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
      String[] splitBySpaces = c.element().split(" ");
      c.output(KV.of(splitBySpaces[splitBySpaces.length - 1],c.element()));
    }
  }))
```

and then with `getDestination` we control how to route each element to a different table according to the key and `getTable` to build the fully qualified table name (prepending the prefix). We could use `getSchema` if the different tables had different schemas. Finally, we control what to write in the table using `withFormatFunction`:

```java
.apply(BigQueryIO.<KV<String, String>>write()
.to(new DynamicDestinations<KV<String, String>, String>() {
    public String getDestination(ValueInSingleWindow<KV<String, String>> element) {
        return element.getValue().getKey();
    }
    public TableDestination getTable(String name) {
      String tableSpec = output + name;
        return new TableDestination(tableSpec, "Table for type " + name);
  }
    public TableSchema getSchema(String schema) {
          List<TableFieldSchema> fields = new ArrayList<>();

      fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("Text").setType("STRING"));
      TableSchema ts = new TableSchema();
      ts.setFields(fields);
      return ts;
    }
})
.withFormatFunction(new SerializableFunction<KV<String, String>, TableRow>() {
    public TableRow apply(KV<String, String> row) {
    TableRow tr = new TableRow();

    tr.set("Text", row.getValue());
    return tr;
    }
 })
 .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED));
```

To fully test this I created the following tables:

```sh
bq mk dynamic_key
bq mk -f dynamic_key.dynamic_one Text:STRING
bq mk -f dynamic_key.dynamic_two Text:STRING
```

And, after setting the `$PROJECT`, `$BUCKET` and `$TABLE_PREFIX` (in my case `PROJECT_ID:dynamic_key.dynamic_`) variables, I run the job with:

```sh
mvn -Pdataflow-runner compile -e exec:java \
 -Dexec.mainClass=com.dataflow.samples.DynamicTableFromKey \
      -Dexec.args="--project=$PROJECT \
      --stagingLocation=gs://$BUCKET/staging/ \
      --tempLocation=gs://$BUCKET/temp/ \
      --output=$TABLE_PREFIX \
      --runner=DataflowRunner"
```

We can verify that each element went to the correct table:

```sh
$ bq query "SELECT * FROM dynamic_key.dynamic_one"
+---------------------------------+
|              Text               |
+---------------------------------+
| please, table one               |
| Back to one                     |
| My fave is one                  |
| this should go to table one     |
| I would like to go to table one |
+---------------------------------+
```

```sh
$ bq query "SELECT * FROM dynamic_key.dynamic_two"
+--------------------+
|        Text        |
+--------------------+
| I prefer table two |
| Rooting for two    |
+--------------------+
```

Full code [here](https://gist.github.com/gxercavins/0b8a1bbb8591fb981e03662f9501af21).

Comment: Thanks alot for this detailed explanation. I didnt knew about withFormatFunction. It just saved alot of efforts.